# TensorflowJS library works on localhost but no longer works once I deploy to Netlify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tensorflow, jsx, netlify

I followed [this](https://hackernoon.com/tensorflow-js-real-time-object-detection-in-10-lines-of-code-baf15dfb95b2) tutorial to implement the COCOSSD object detection model into my frontend. I installed the node modules with npm I @tensorflow/tfjs and npm I @tensorflow-models/coco-ssd. The web app is frontend-only and meant to be that way, the object detection model works great on localhost however once I deployed to Netlify via npm run build, netlify deploy --prod it no longer works. I have confirmed that it is not an issue with the camera.

Here is my code for the model implementation:

```
import * as cocoSsd from '@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs';

class Detector extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      list: ['person','laptop','scissors','mouse', 'spoon', 'keyboard',],
      isStopped: true,
    }
  } 
  videoRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      const webCamPromise = navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          audio: false,
          video: {
            facingMode: "user"
          }
        })
        .then(stream => {
          window.stream = stream;
          this.videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.videoRef.current.onloadedmetadata = () => {
              resolve();
            };
          });
        });
      const modelPromise = cocoSsd.load();
      Promise.all([modelPromise, webCamPromise])
        .then(values => {
          this.detectFrame(this.videoRef.current, values[0]);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  }

  detectFrame = (video, model) => {
    model.detect(video).then(predictions => {
      this.checkPredictions(predictions);
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.detectFrame(video, model);
      });
    });
  };

  checkPredictions = predictions => {
    predictions.forEach(prediction => {
      if(prediction.class === this.state.list[0]) {
        const tempL = this.state.list;
        const tempC = this.state.count + 1;
        tempL.shift();
        this.setState({list: tempL, count: tempC, isStopped: false});
      }
    });
  };

  //render statements etc. irrelevant to the issue I believe
```

May someone please help I spent several hours building this thing and am extremely disappointed to find out it doesn't work once I deployed.

Comment: what error are you getting in the console?

Comment: Sorry I sohuld have included this. I am getting a type error it says cannot call class Detector as a function